# How to add html template in multiple locations using jquery append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First off I'm sorry if this has already been answered as I tried to find the answer but I'm not sure how to word my question. Basically what I am trying to do is take some template html:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-info">
   <table> ...... </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then add it in multiple places using jquery.append(). Something like this:

Js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".fillme").append(...what goes here);
}
```

Html View:

```
<body>
 <div class="fillme"></div>
</body>
```

Thank you for all your help and if you need anymore information let me know and I will try to explain the best I can thanks!

**EDIT**
Ok so I think I have a better way to try and do this be need some help with getting it to work. What I am doing now is placing the template content html from before in a script tag which is in the index html file before my js file which contains the jquery from before. Is it possible for me to get the html from script tag and append it to the divs I want and how should I go about doing it??

Comment: Is not possible to create template html with javascript and would append it into multiple places?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to apply a template would be to create a string of the template you want to apply, and then call `$(".fillme").append(string);`

```
var template = '<div class="content">';
template += '<div class="content-info">';
template += '<table> ...... </table>';
template += '</div>';
template += '</div>';

$(".fillme").append(template);
```

Alternatively, you can use `$('.fillme').load(url);` to load the content into a container.  In this instance, url would need to be a reference to a file in the web site, that contains html content.

Comment: I agree this is the easiest way but to me it seems harder to maintain and keep clean. because I plan to have quite a few divs which will hold different content I want to place on my site.

Comment: @Josh I added an alternative solution, which involves keeping the templates in a separate file(s), and then using `$.load()` to fill the content.

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work. If I am using the default folder structure that asp.net mvc creates for you and I place the template file in the views/shared folder I would get access to that file with this path: "~/Views/Shared/TemplateFile.cshtml" correct??

Comment: Yes, if you want to go from root, it would be '~/path/to/file'. Are you getting any errors in the console, or anything that indicates there might be a problem?

Comment: It says 403 forbidden. Is that because its trying to load a correct html page. Because I dont want the template to be an actual page but rather a file which holds multiple divs that are templates for content I wish to show at different location on my site.

Comment: You can't load specific content from a page. The $.load() call will load the entire page. You would need to have a file for each template to use $.load().

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$(".fillme").append($(".content").html());
```

Comment: I've this and thought this was the way to go. But for me it doesnt seem to be working or I'm doing it wrong. I have the template in another file called ContentTemplates.cshtml and before I include my javascript file I do this: <use file="~/Views/Shared/ContentTemplates.cshtml"/>. any ideas???

Comment: have you made sure that you run it after window load?

Comment: yeah, try console.log($(".content").length) to check if there is actually a content when code is run

Comment: Then you must be loading your template after your main page loads, so when code runs the template has not been loaded yet

Comment: How would I make the template load. I have the template in a file under the Views/Shard folder and in my Index.cshtml at the top I do this: <use file="~/Views/Shared/ContentTemplate.cshtml"/>, is there something wrong with that??

Comment: Sorry I don't really know about .cshtml, maybe you can load it by ajax?

Comment: How would I load it with ajax?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
or at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_load.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$(".content").clone().appendTo(".fillme", "sector2" , "selector3" , ...);
```

Clone it and append to multiple places you want by specifying multiple selectors.